# Why does C not allow concatenating strings when using the conditional operator?

Tags: c, string, syntax, concatenation, conditional-operator

The following code compiles without problems:

```
int main() {
    printf("Hi" "Bye");
}
```

However, this does not compile:

```
int main() {
    int test = 0;
    printf("Hi" (test ? "Bye" : "Goodbye"));
}
```

What is the reason for that?

Comment: String concatenation is part of the early lexing phase; it's not part of the expression synatx of C. In other words, there is no *value* of type "string literal". Rather, string literals are lexical elements of the source code that form values.

Comment: Just to clarify @KerrekSB answer - concatenation of the strings is a part of preprocessing of the code text *prior* compiling it. While the ternary operator is evaluated in the runtime, after the code is compiled (or in case everything is constant it can be done in the compile-time).

Comment: Where would the result of the concatenation be stored? How long would it remain valid?

Comment: There is no builtin dynamic string concatenation operator in C.  If you want to dynamically concatenate strings, you must allocate storage for them, then use something like `strcat` or `sprintf`.

Comment: Detail: In this post, `"Hi"` and `"Bye"` are _string literals_, not _strings_ as used in the C standard library.  With _string literals_, the compiler will concatenate `"H\0i" "B\0ye"`.  Not the same with `sprintf(buf,"%s%s", "H\0i" "B\0ye");`

Comment: If you really want to concatenate using a constant for control, you can do it via `#define`. And here, the value of `test` is actually unknown to the compiler, since this is not a constant, but a variable.

Comment: More-or-less the same reason you can't do `a (some_condition ? + : - ) b`

Comment: Note that even `printf("Hi" ("Bye"));` won't work — it doesn't require the ternary operator; the parenthesis is sufficient (though `printf("Hi" test ? "Bye" : "Goodbye")` also wouldn't compile).  There are only a limited number of tokens that can follow a string literal.  Comma `,`, open square bracket `[`, close square bracket `]` (as in `1["abc"]` — and yes, it is gruesome), close round bracket `)`, close curly bracket `}` (in an initializer or similar context), and semicolon `;` are legitimate (and another string literal); I'm not sure there are any others.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You missed `L`, as in `L"Wide " L"String"`, ` + ` (as in `"Hello" + 1` which is a pointer to `"ello") and `-` (same as +), '==' obviously, and possibly di/trigraphs equivalents of all these.

Comment: @MSalters: Thank! Yes, I didn't think of `L` as able to follow a string literal because I was thinking that it (and the C11 `u`, `U` and `u8` prefixes) come before the string, not after it. But if you have `L"long" L"short"` as adjacent (wide character) string literals, then the `L` can appear after the close quote of the first string.  Similarly with the `u` and `U` and `u8` prefixes too. The `+` and `-` operators are relevant; the relational operators are syntactically legitimate but of dubious semantic value.  There are digraph and trigraph synonyms for `{}[]` in theory.

Comment: @MSalters: I suppose you could have `#define M(x) "prefix" # x` too (and there's a digraph and trigraph for `#`).  Notable omissions from these possibilities include `(` and 'identifier' — I don't think they're ever valid.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Well, if you consider macro's, then `"prefix" FOO` can be legal depending on what it will be replaced with. But of course, in the phases of translation where macros are not yet replaced, you don't have identifiers yet.

Comment: @MSalters: Ugh...yes.  It's a delicate proposition saying "it can't be done" in C.

Comment: @MSalters Is the L not part of the string literal token?

Comment: @immibis: Yes, but I was talking about the situation where you had two adjacent wide string tokens. The second L follows the first string literal.

Comment: @MSalters Is the L not part of the *second* string literal token?

Comment: @immibis : It is, yes.

Comment: @MSalters In that case, an `L` token is not able to follow a string literal - it is a string literal following another string literal.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

According to the C Standard (5.1.1.2 Translation phases)

> 1 The precedence among the syntax rules of translation is specified by
>   the following phases.6)
>
> 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

And only after that

> 7. White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant. Each 
>      preprocessing token is converted into a token. **The resulting
>      tokens are syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a
>      translation unit**.

In this construction

```
"Hi" (test ? "Bye" : "Goodbye")
```

there are no adjacent string literal tokens. So this construction is invalid.

Comment: This only repeats the assertion that it's not allowed in C. It does not explain _why_, which was the question. Don't know why it accumulated 26 upvotes in 5 hours.... and the accept, no less! Congratulations.

Comment: Have to agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit here. Why shouldn't `(test ? "Bye" : "Goodbye")` evaulate to either of the string literals essentially _making_ `"Hi" "Bye"` or `"Hi Goodbye"`? (my question is answered in the other answers)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, because when  people normally ask why something doesn't compile in C, they're asking for clarification on which rule it breaks, not why *Standards Authors of Antiquity* chose it to be that way.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The question you describe would probably be off topic. I can't see any *technical* reason why it wouldn't be possible to implement that, so without a definitive answer from the authors of the specification, all answers would be opinion based. And it would generally not fall into the category of "practical" or "answerable" questions (as the [help/dont-ask] indicates we require).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's explains *why*: "because C standard said so". Question about why this rule is defined as defined would be off topic.

Comment: @user11153: An answer "because it is" is 100% useless. See my answer for how this question _should_ be approached (and there's nothing "off topic" about it - what?!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *'And an answer "because it is" is 100% useless.'* - many answers on C/C++ question are *"Here is why: <quote form the spec>"*. They are all useless? This answers could be better, but it is a valid answer.

Comment: @user11153: It depends on the question.... Come on, this is easy! When someone wants to know how the standard defines something, then quoting the standard obviously makes sense. When someone asks "why does C not allow <X>" then quoting the passage showing that C does not allow <X> is useless. You're not answering the question: you're merely affirming its premise.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit a sufficiently clever compiler (disregarding the standard) could inline the ternary operator in this case, making what's left concatenatable by current rules. In your answer you're only moving the "why" to "why doens't the preprocessor know about the value of `test`".  What about `"a" (0 ? "b" : "c")`? Certainly  the precompiler would know about `0`? These are the exact questions that require a standards reference. Explaining the motivation might be interesting, but inferring that it _has_ to be this way absent of a standard is generally not true.

Comment: @thebjorn: That works in _this_ case, but not in the general case. That's why the language rule cannot account for it. Yes I am "only" moving the why to that question because that is the important question that is the entire reason for this behaviour. And the answer is pretty obvious. In general, `test` could come from absolutely anywhere.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if you look at Lisp macros or immediate words in Forth, there is no reason a sufficiently clever preprocessor/macro-language could not account for the general case. (but that's not C, because C is the language as defined defined by...)

Comment: @thebjorn: How could these concatenations be performed at compile-time when "the thing to concatenate" is not known until four years later, two hundred miles away? You would have to pre-store the result of both possibilities (which is an available choice to be sure - not a great one but hey) or do the concat at run-time. The latter probably covers the "you could do this" part. At _this_ point you can say "the standard decided literal concat would take place at compile-time", fine ;) Though there are philosophical reasons you can give for that to complete the story.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit fair enough, although in this case simple constant evaluation at compile time would obviate the need for any runtime support :-)  fwiw/imho, Sourav Ghosh is probably the best answer at this point..

Comment: @thebjorn: I think so too

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The fact it can't be preconcatenated at compile time does not exclude the possibility that runtime concatenation could be inferred from the resulting type of the ternary without the explicit concatenation symbol. So this code *could* work if the compilers implemented it. The why *is* only because of the specification (and the fact that compilers adhere to the spec). The question says *nothing* specifically about compile time concatenation.

Comment: @jpmc26: _"the concatenation could be inferred from the resulting type of the ternary without the explicit concatenation symbol"_ Sorry, I didn't understand this. Could you rephrase?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The OP sees that two consecutive strings are automatically concatenated: `"Hi" "Bye"`. There's no reason the compiler could not analyze the ternary, see that it results in a string (in this case, it clearly always results in a string), and generate code that concatenates the strings at runtime. In other words, it could act as if there was an implicit `strcat` call on the two strings. So the only "why" is because the language designers chose not to bother.

Comment: @jpmc26: Oh, okay, well I already conceded that the concatenation could be done at runtime.... six hours ago!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Rather than criticize the answer, which makes a good-faith attempt to answer the question, instead criticize the question. "Why" questions are *vague*. Why does program X exhibit behaviour Y?  Because that's what the spec says. Why does the spec say that? Because that's what the designers wrote. Why did the designers write that? Because they had twenty hours of vigorous debate about the pros and cons, and arrived at this as a reasonable compromise. Why this compromise and not another?  Blah blah blah, it goes on forever.  **Reject the question**.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: A better question would be  *answerable*. "What section of the specification describes this rule?" is answerable. Even "what considerations motivated this design decision?" is a question that has an answer; the answer might be known by only a few people, but it's a question with an answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You really do need to understand that the explanation given in this answer is sufficient: the language specification says so. Lexical concatenation precedes expression parsing. **Your own answer* says exactly the same thing.

Comment: @EJP: "You really do need to understand" is a pretty arrogant thing to say when you really mean "I disagree with your opinion", and when you're objectively wrong. _My own answer_ does **not** say "exactly the same thing". I don't know why I have to keep repeating this, but I'll do so one final time. This answer merely quotes the standard and repeats the question's premise that "this construction is invalid" (truthful, but adds nothing). My answer attempts to explain _why_ this is the case. Now read the question again. "_Why_ does C not allow..." Hope that helps.

Answer (score 137):

As per the C11 standard, chapter §5.1.1.2, concatenation of adjacent string literals:

> Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

happens in **translation phase**. On the other hand:

```
printf("Hi" (test ? "Bye" : "Goodbye"));
```

involves the conditional operator, which is evaluated at **run-time**. So, at compile time, during the translation phase, there are no adjacent string literals present, hence the concatenation is not possible. The syntax is invalid and thus reported by your compiler.

---

To elaborate a bit on the ***why*** part, during the preprocessing phase, the adjacent string literals are concatenated and represented as a single *string literal* (token). The storage is allocated accordingly and the concatenated string literal is considered as a *single entity* (one string literal).

On the other hand, in case of run-time concatenation, the destination should have enough memory to hold the concatenated *string literal* otherwise, there will be no way that the *expected* concatenated output can be accessed. Now, in case of *string literals*, they are already allocated memory at compile-time and cannot be *extended* to fit in any more incoming input *into* or *appended to* the original content. In other words, there will be no way that the concatenated result can be accessed (presented) as a single *string literal*. So, this construct in inherently incorrect.

Just FYI, for run-time **string** (*not literals*) concatenation, we have the library function [`strcat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) which concatenates two *strings*. Notice, the description mentions:

> `char *strcat(char * restrict s1,const char * restrict s2);`
>
> The `strcat()` function appends a copy of the string pointed to by `s2` (including the
>   terminating null character) to the end of the **string pointed to by `s1`**. The initial character
>   of `s2` overwrites the null character at the end of `s1`. [...]

So, we can see, the `s1` is a **string**, not a **string literal**. However, as the content of `s2` is not altered in any way, it can very well be a *string literal*.

Comment: you might want to add an extra explanation about `strcat`: the destination array must be long enough to receive the characters from `s2` plus a null terminator after the characters present there already.

Answer (score 41):

String literal concatenation is performed by the preprocessor at compile-time. There is no way for this concatenation to be aware of the value of `test`, which is not known until the program actually executes. Therefore, these string literals cannot be concatenated.

Because the general case is that you wouldn't have a construction like this for values known at compile-time, the C standard was designed to restrict the auto-concatenation feature to the most basic case: when the literals are literally right alongside each other.

But even if it did not word this restriction in that way, or if the restriction were differently-constructed, your example would still be impossible to realise without making the concatenation a runtime process. And, for that, we have the library functions such as `strcat`.

Comment: I just read assumptions. While what you say is pretty much valid, you can't provide sources for it since there are none. The only source in regards to C is the standard document which (while it is in many cases obvisious) doesn't state why some things are the way they are but just states that they have to be that specific way. So beeing that nit-picky about Vlad from Moscow's answer is inappropiate. Since OP can be breaken down to "Why is it that way?" -Where the only correct sourced answer is "Because it is C, and thats the way C is defined" thats the only literarly straight correct answer.

Comment: This is (admited) lacking of explanation. But here again beeing said is Vlad's answer serving much more as an explanation to the core problem then yours does. Again said: While the information you give I can confirm is related and correct, I disaggree with your complaints. and while I wouldn't consider you'rs offtopic aswell, its from my POV more offtopic then Vlads actually is.

Comment: @Zaibis: The source is me. Vlad's answer is not an explanation at all; it is merely a confirmation of the premise of the question. Certainly neither of them is "off topic" (you might want to look up what that term means). But you are entitled to your opinion.

Comment: Even after reading above comments, I still wonder who downvoted this answer ᶘ ᵒᴥᵒᶅ I believe this is a perfect answer unless OP asks for further clarifications on this answer.

Comment: I am unable to distinguish why this answer is acceptable to you and @VladfromMoscow's isn't, when they both say the same thing, and when his is backed by a citation and yours isn't.

Comment: @EJP: OMG. This _again_. They do **not** say the same thing. His repeats the premise of the question. Mine answers it. Do a diff on the two pieces of text; you'll see that they are _quite_ different.

Answer (score 31):

Because C has no `string` type. String literals are compiled to `char` arrays, referenced by a `char*` pointer.

C allows adjacent *literals* to be combined *at compile-time*, as in your first example. The C compiler itself has some knowledge about strings. But this information is *not present at runtime,* and thus concatenation cannot happen.

During the compilation process, your first example is "translated" to:

```
int main() {
    static const char char_ptr_1[] = {'H', 'i', 'B', 'y', 'e', '\0'};
    printf(char_ptr_1);
}
```

Note how the two strings are combined to a single static array by the compiler, before the program ever executes.

However, your second example is "translated" to something like this:

```
int main() {
    static const char char_ptr_1[] = {'H', 'i', '\0'};
    static const char char_ptr_2[] = {'B', 'y', 'e', '\0'};
    static const char char_ptr_3[] = {'G', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'b', 'y', 'e', '\0'};
    int test = 0;
    printf(char_ptr_1 (test ? char_ptr_2 : char_ptr_3));
}
```

It should be clear why this does not compile. The ternary operator `?` is evaluated at runtime, not compile-time, when the "strings" no longer exist as such, but only as simple `char` arrays, referenced by `char*` pointers. Unlike adjacent *string literals*, adjacent *char pointers* are simply a syntax error.

Comment: Excellent answer, possibly the best here. "It should be clear why this does not compile." You might consider expanding that with "because the ternary operator is a conditional evaluated at *run time* not *compile time*".

Comment: Shouldn't `static const char *char_ptr_1 = {'H', 'i', 'B', 'y', 'e', '\0'};` be `static const char *char_ptr_1 = "HiBye";` and similarly for the rest of the pointers?

Comment: @CoolGuy When you write `static const char *char_ptr_1 = "HiBye";` the compiler translates the line to `static const char *char_ptr_1 = {'H', 'i', 'B', 'y', 'e', '\0'};`, so no, it should not be wrote "like a string". As the Answer says, strings are compiled to an array of chars, and if you were assigning an array of chars in it's most "raw" form, you would use a comma separated list of chars, just like `static const char *char_ptr_1 = {'H', 'i', 'B', 'y', 'e', '\0'};`

Comment: @Ankush Yes. But although `static const char str[] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'};` is the same as `static const char str[] = "test";`, `static const char* ptr = "test";` is _not_ the same as `static const char* ptr = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'};`. The former is valid and will compile but the latter is invalid and does do what you expect.

Comment: I have fleshed out the last paragraph and corrected the code examples, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

If you really want to have both branches produce compile-time string constants to be chosen at runtime, you'll need a macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ccat(s, t, a, b) ((t)?(s a):(s b))

int
main ( int argc, char **argv){
  printf("%s\n", ccat("hello ", argc > 2 , "y'all", "you"));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

> What is the reason for that?

Your code using ternary operator conditionally chooses between two string literals. No matter condition known or unknown, this can't be evaluated at compile time, so it can't compile. Even this statement `printf("Hi" (1 ? "Bye" : "Goodbye"));` wouldn't compile. The reason is in depth explained in the answers above. Another possibility of *making such a statement using ternary operator valid to compile*, would also involve a *format tag* and the result of the ternary operator statement formatted as *additional argument* to `printf`. Even then, `printf()` printout would give an impression of "having concatenated" those strings only at, and as early as *runtime*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int test = 0;
    printf("Hi %s\n", (test ? "Bye" : "Goodbye")); //specify format and print as result
}
```

Comment: SO is not a Tutorial site. You should give an Answer to the OP and not a tutorial.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. It may be an attempt to solve the OP's underlying problem, but we don't really know what that is.

Comment: `printf` doesn't *require* a format specifier; if only the concatenation were done at compile time (which it isn't), OP's use of printf would be valid.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, @David Conrad. My sloppy wording would indeed make appear as if stating  `printf()` would require a format tag, which is absolutely not true. Corrected!

Comment: That's a better wording. +1 Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In `printf("Hi" "Bye");` you have two consecutive arrays of char which the compiler can make into a single array.

In `printf("Hi" (test ? "Bye" : "Goodbye"));` you have one array followed by a pointer to char (an array converted to a pointer to its first element). The compiler cannot *merge* an array and a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question - I would go to the definition of printf. The function printf expects **const char*** as argument. Any string literal such as "Hi" is a const char*; however an expression such as `(test)? "str1" : "str2"` is NOT a const char* because the result of such expression is found only at run-time and hence is indeterminate at compile time, a fact which duly causes the compiler to complain. On the other hand - this works perfectly well `printf("hi %s", test? "yes":"no")`

Comment: *however an expression such as `(test)? "str1" : "str2"` is NOT a `const char*`... Of course it is! It is not a constant expression, but its type **is** `const char *`. It would be perfectly fine to write `printf(test ? "hi " "yes" : "hi " "no")`. The OP's problem has nothing to do with `printf`, `"Hi" (test ? "Bye" : "Goodbye")` is a syntax error no matter what the expression context is.

Comment: Agreed. I confused the output of an expression with the expression itself

Answer (score -4):

This does not compile because the parameter list for the printf function is

```
(const char *format, ...)
```

and

```
("Hi" (test ? "Bye" : "Goodbye"))
```

does not fit the parameter list.

gcc tries to make sense of it by imagining that

```
(test ? "Bye" : "Goodbye")
```

is a parameter list, and complains that "Hi" is not a function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're right that it doesn't match the `printf()` argument list, but that's because the expression isn't valid anywhere — not just in a `printf()` argument list. In other words, you've picked a far too specialized reason for the problem; the general problem is that `"Hi" (` is not valid in C, let alone in a call to `printf()`.  I suggest you delete this answer before it is down-voted.

Comment: That is not how C works. This is not parsed as trying to call a string literal like PHP.